# Lightning Radio/Checkbox option level helptext

Tags: lightning-web-components

Just wondering if it is possible in LWC to provide help text at a option level for radio-group or checkbox-group?
We are wanting to provide further details about why a user might select each option.

If it were something to be added in future it could be done perhaps as part of the js used for defining the options

```js
    yesNoOptions = [
        {label: 'Yes', value: 'yes'},
        {label: 'No', value: 'no'},
        {label: 'Not provided', value: 'N/A', helptext='Select this option if you were provided a form before 01/09/2019'},
    ];
```

Interestingly the radio-group does not support **field-level-help** for providing help at a question level according to the lightning-input documentation which DOES offer that attribute - https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-input/specification

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for an OOTB solution for this myself, but out of luck. Just rolled my own.
Here you go.

**HTML**

```
<template>
<fieldset class="slds-form-element">
    <legend class="slds-form-element__legend slds-form-element__label">{label}</legend>
    <div class="slds-form-element__control">
        <div class="slds-radio">
            <table class="lwcir_radio_table">
                <template for:each={referencedOptions} for:item="option" for:index="opt_index">
                    <tr key={option.id}>
                        <td>
                            <div class="lwcir_radio_input">
                                <input type="radio"
                                       name={groupName}
                                       id={option.id}
                                       value={option.value}
                                       checked={option.checked}
                                       onchange={handleInputChange}
                                       required={required} />
                                <label class="slds-radio__label" for={option.id}>
                                    <span class="slds-radio_faux"></span>
                                    <span class="slds-form-element__label">{option.label}</span>
                                </label>
                            </div>
                        </td>
                        <td if:true={option.hasHelp}>
                            <lightning-helptext content={option.help}></lightning-helptext>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </template>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</fieldset>
```

**Javascript**

```
import {LightningElement, api, track} from 'lwc';
export default class LwcInputRadio extends LightningElement {
    @api label;
    @api groupName;
    @api required = false;
    @track selected;
    referencedOptions;
    @api
    set options(ops) {

        let asObject = [];
        if (ops != null) {
            if(typeof ops === "string") {
                asObject = JSON.parse(ops);

            } else {
                //Must make copy of object before modifying due to LockerService.
                asObject = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(ops));
            }
            for (let i = 0;  Array.isArray(asObject) && i < asObject.length; i++) {
                asObject[i].id = asObject[i].value + "-" + i;
                asObject[i].hasHelp = asObject[i]["help"] != null && asObject[i]["help"] !== "";
                asObject[i].checked = false;
            }
        }
        this.referencedOptions = asObject;
    }

    get options() {
        return this.referencedOptions;
    }

    handleInputChange(event) {
        this.selected = event.target.value;
        this.referencedOptions.forEach(option => option.checked = option.value === this.selected);
        this.dispatchChangeEvent();
    }

    dispatchChangeEvent() {
        const changeEvent = new CustomEvent("delta", {
            detail: {
                value : this.selected,
            }
        });
        this.dispatchEvent(changeEvent);
    }
}
```

I'm using it from an aura component, but it would look something like this:

```
<aura:attribute name="myOptions" type="List" default="[
        {'label': 'Option 1', 'value': 'VAL_1','help':'My help text for 1'},
        {'label': 'Option 2', 'value': 'VAL_2','help':'My help text for 2'},
        {'label': 'Option 3', 'value': 'VAL_3','help':'My help text for 3'},
    ]"/>

 <c:lwc_Input_Radio
    options="{!v.myOptions}"
    label="Radio Options"
    required="true"
    ondelta="{!c.handleChangeEvent}"
    groupName="myRadioGroup">
  </c:lwc_Input_Radio>
```